# Cumulative sums for the previous row

Tags: r, sum, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get cumulative sums for the previous row/year. Running `cumsum(data$fonds)` gives me the running totals of adjacent sells, which doesn't work for what I want to do. I would like to have my data look like the following:

```
   year      fond   cumsum  
1  1950       0       0  
2  1951       1       0
3  1952       3       1
4  1953       0       4
5  1954       0       4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: cumsum needs to follow over from the previous year's total so 4 for 1954 is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data$cumsum <- c(0, cumsum(data$fonds)[-nrow(data)])
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can use the `shift` function.  By default, it gives `type="lag"`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Cumsum := cumsum(shift(fond, fill= 0))]
```